# What of this array is on the stack or heap?

Tags: c++

Can pc_TcpClientList depend on how the C_TcpSocketAccess is declared to determine if it is on the stack or heap?
Or is pc_TcpClientList an array(that is on the stack) with a bunch of pointers basically if you use `pRef = &pc_TcpClientList[idx]` .

```
class C_TcpSocketAccess : public SAP::C_TcpSocket
{
public:
  C_TcpSocket pc_TcpClientList[65]; //this is on the stack? or it depends where C_TcpSocketAccess is put?
};


{
  C_TcpSocketAccess pcat;// pcat is on the stack
  pcat.pc_TcpClientList; // pc_TcpClientListis on the stack because pcat is on the stack
  

  C_TcpSocketAccess *pdog = new C_TcpSocketAccess();  // pdog is on the heap
  pdog->pc_TcpClientList;                             // pc_TcpClientList is on the heap because pdog is on the heap?
}
```

Comment: It's part of the same object in the same location.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: And it could be in fairy dust or human blood. It's uncommon to see otherwise, but not everyone uses stacks and heaps.

Comment: *it depends where C_TcpSocketAccess is put?* yep.

Comment: "If a window is part of a house, is the window in the city or outside the city?" -> It's wherever the house is.

Comment: @MooingDuck we of course exclude cases of 5-dimensional houses (The House That Jack Built)

Comment: *The House That Jack Built* Whenever I read or hear that I think of Marvel Comics.

Answer (score 1):

```
C_TcpSocketAccess pcat //object is not on the heap and so //pc_TcpClientList[65] is also not on the heap
```

If you allocate memory for your object on the heap then the array which is a part of the object would also be on the heap. Likewise if you use stack allocation.

```
C_TcpSocket C_TcpSocketAccess::pc_TcpClientList[65];
```

As per your declaration `pc_TcpClientList` is an array of `C_TcpSocket`s regardless of where `C_TcpSocketAccess` is created. Remember when you allocate on the heap you need to clean up once a heap object's job is done otherwise you end up with a memory leak.

Vectors is what I would recommend instead of using statically allocated arrays:

```
#include <vector>

class C_TcpSocketAccess : public SAP::C_TcpSocket
{
public:
  std::vector<C_TcpSocket> cTcpClientList; 
};

//usage in some function

{
  C_TcpSocketAccess cTcpSockAcc;
  C_TcpSocket aSocket;
  cTcpSockAcc.cTcpClientList.push_back(aSocket);
}
```